# High current (~100A) linear regulation

Tags: constant-current, high-current, load-regulation

Hello I need to drive resistive load of 0.25 OHM. I have 24V 100A power source available.
I use computer to measure operating conditions, but as response I need to control current and by this performance of the load.

Normally (for low current application) I would use transistor, but for this level of power it is far beyond any specs and also creates amount of heat that can not be cooled reasonably.

Use PWM or linear regulation?

- my preference would be linear regulation (arduino drived constant current circuit)
- another aspect is very bad experience with PWM (noisy, unexpected results, sensitive to components placement, wire lengths...)

This will be driven by MCU, and the resulation must be "linear" between 10W and 2500W. MCU is not yet selected... raspberry pi, arduino, esp32...

How would you approach regulation like this? Thanks for any ideas.

Edit: Answers to questions from comments:

- The power supply is 230V AC input and 24V DC output
- The PWM frequency is unknown, if there will be linear regulation it is expected (qualigied guess) that during startup there will be ~5 regulation changes during second, after startup it is expected to change regulation once in 10 seconds

Comment: What is the time constant of the system of interest? In other words, how low can the PWM frequency be?

Comment: What is the thermal response time of the resistor? Is it possible to control the output voltage of the power supply or modify it to do so? Is the power supply AC or DC?

Comment: 24V is DC, power source is blackbox no possible to change, IF (!) there will be linear regulation it is expected ~5 changes per second during startup and then one regulation change in cca 10 seconds (also added to question)

Comment: A linear regulator on its own won't work because the maximum current that could be produced is 96 amps (theoretical).

Comment: https://www.analog.com/media/en/technical-documentation/data-sheets/ltc7871.pdf

Comment: @Andyaka Thank you, never heard of, but seems very interesting! Lot of material to study in long winter evenings, but seems like way forward

Comment: If this is a one of a type thing just purchase an electronic load (test instrument), all of the work is done for you.

Comment: I would look at some sort of buck converter configured as a constant current source.  Insert your uC of choice to allow adjusting/changing the output.

Comment: Are you married to this resistor, or can you change it to something more practical, with more ohms and less amps?